# Page is not showing while using a component for styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a container to simplify some styling while learning React and I am having some issues.

Currently this is my Component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

const FormContainer = ({ childern }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
        <Col xs={12} md={6}>
          {childern}
          </Col> 
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default FormContainer
```

And this is where I am loading it into

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer'
import { login } from '../actions/userActions'



const LoginScreen = ({location, history}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)

  const {loading, error, userInfo} = userLogin

  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/' // Takes location of Url, splits after the equals sign, and everything right of it or takes us back to '/'

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(userInfo) {
      history.push(redirect)
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, redirect])
  
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
   dispatch(login(email, password))
  }

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loader/>}
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId='email'>
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type='email' placeholder="Enter email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}>

          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        
          <Form.Group controlId='password'>
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type='password' placeholder="Enter password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}>
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </Form>
        <Row className='py-3'>
          <Col>
          New Customer <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : '/register'}>
            Register
          </Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
     </FormContainer>
      )
}

      export default LoginScreen
```

When I remove FormContainer and replace it with a div the LoginScreen info shows up but without the styling. Otherwise it is blank with no issues in the Console. My other components seem to to show some stuff, but not the text.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have a typo with "children"

Comment: Typo, there is no passed `childern` prop, but I'm sure you meant to destructure and use the `children` prop. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".